# Colorbox + ASP.NET WebForm Submit Button

Tags: asp.net, webforms, colorbox

I am having trouble using a Colorbox with an ASP.NET WebForm inside. What I am trying to do is:

1. User clicks a link, and the colorbox pops up
2. Inside colorbox, user enters a term in a textbox and clicks submit button
3. On submit, the page hits the DB and then shows results (still inside the colorbox)

Right now, I have steps #1 & #2 working, but #3 isn't. If I click the submit button, the browser navigates to the page that was loaded inside the colorbox (FAQ.aspx).

Test.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link href="css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
     <a class="cbox">FAQs</a>
   </div>
   </form>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var colorbox = $("#colorbox");
        $('form#Form1').prepend(colorbox);
      });
      $('a.cbox').colorbox({ href: "FAQ.aspx" });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

FAQ.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>Frequently Asked Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    Search: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" /> <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmitSearch" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitSearch_Click"/>
    <br />
    <asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="litOutput" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmitSearch" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the colorbox content inside an iframe:

```
$('a.cbox').colorbox({ href: "FAQ.aspx", iframe: true, width: 456, height: 100 });
```